# Error in Nullable Value Types in WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am facing the below issue following

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187557.aspx (Section "Input Parameter Handling", but the suggested solution seems NOT WORKING). It seems that the **NullableInteger** passed in is always treated as **Empty String** and NOT **Null Value**

I created a MessageContract which contains a nullable type for Integer as shown below:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xsTongue Tiedequence>
:
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InputSub1" type="tnsTongue TiedubClass"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NullableInteger" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
    </xsTongue Tiedequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I am using SoapUI to test for the nullable integer with following SOAP Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlnsTongue Tiedoapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:myw="MyWCFTest">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <myw:MessageRequest>
     <myw:InputSub1>
        <mywTongue TiedubProperty1>USD</mywTongue TiedubProperty1>
     </myw:InputSub1>
     <myw:NullableInteger myw:nil="true" />
  </myw:MessageRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, it always throws error with the following abbreviated description:

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>                        at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)    at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToInt32(String s)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderIServiceDemo1.Read3_NullableOfInt32(Boolean
>   checkType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderIServiceDemo1.Read5_MessageRequest()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer1.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader
>   reader)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents
>   events)
>                        System.FormatException

**Note:** I am facing an exact same issue and when I google I found this was already posted here [Error in Nullable Value Types in WCF](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f6fa48e-60b4-4034-9a46-c65f8185ff4d/problem-in-nullable-value-types-in-wcf?forum=wcf) but with hardly any answer. I am posting it here(StackOverflow) to gain more attention.

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Comment: @spodger it makes sense but i am yet to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to handle the nullable behind the code

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int? NullableIntegerCount{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("NullableInteger")]
    public string NullableIntegerText
    {
        get { return this.NumberOfPagesCount.HasValue ? this.NullableIntegerCount.Value.ToString("F2") : string.Empty; }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                this.NullableIntegerCount= Convert.ToInt32(value);
            }
            else
            {
                this.NullableIntegerCount= null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nil` attribute doesn't exist in your namespace `xmlns:myw="MyWCFTest`.

It's part of the XML schema namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

Add a reference to this in your root element, `<soapenv:Envelope>`, as follows

`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and then reference the nil attribute using that alias, i.e. `xsi:nil="true"`.